# The second EditText Doesn't get Request focuse in android

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-edittext

i have two EditText and want when the text count becomes 11 then it jumps to another EditText. I want to refactor this process to another class named UIHelper and call the method and pass the first and second EditText and view and it do it.
this is what everything that i did:

in the UIHelper.class:

```
  public static void NextFocous( int et1, int et2,int size, View view){
        ed_size=size;

            edit1 = (EditText) view.findViewById(et1);
            edit2 = (EditText) view.findViewById(et2);

        edit1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                int char_count=s.length();
                Log.d("char1", String.valueOf(char_count));
                if(char_count==ed_size) {

                    edit2.requestFocus();

                    Log.d("char1", "if executed");
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            }
        });
    }
```

and call it like this in the fragment:

```
public class _step5_Fragment_Payment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener{


    public _step5_Fragment_Payment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
View view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag_menu_step5_payment, container, false);
UIHelper.NextFocous(R.id.drug_username,R.id.drug_password,11,view);
  return view;
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems to work for me , what is the problem?

Comment: it doesn't jump to another edit text but when i do in dirty ways i mean do all process in onCreateView then it works fine